# Java - Issue with input.next() and input.nextInt();

Tags: java, zip

I am doing a project for school where we make a class "Animal" and subclasses of different type of Animals. We must insert the animals into an ArrayList and take the input from a file, "Unit4TakehomeInput.txt". The issue that I am having is that when scanning the input from the file, it is not just scanning one line, and I do not understand why?

Here is the Class Animal:

```
package FinalProject;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Scanner;

public abstract class Animal implements Comparable<Animal> {
    static int count = 0;
    String name;
    int birthyear;
    double bill;
    String species;

// Default Constructor
Animal() { count++; }

// Basic Constructor
Animal(String n, int y, double b, String s) {
    count++;
    this.name = n;
    this.birthyear = y;
    this.bill = b;
    this.species = s;
}

// Get Bill Balance
double getBill() { return this.bill; }

// Set Bill Balance
void setBill(double b) { this.bill = b; }

public int compareTo(Animal other) {
    return (int)(100*(this.bill - other.bill));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Animal> aa = getFromFile(args[0]);
        Collections.sort(aa);
        printAnimal(aa);
        System.out.println(Animal.count);
}

static ArrayList<Animal> getFromFile(String inputFile) throws Exception {
File f = new File(inputFile);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(f);
    int total = input.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Animal> al = new ArrayList<Animal>(total);

    for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
        String name = input.next();
        System.out.println(name);
        int year = input.nextInt();
        double bill = input.nextDouble();
        String species = input.next();
        species.toLowerCase();
        switch (species) {
            case "dog":
                int legs = input.nextInt();
                boolean spotty = input.nextBoolean();
                Animal tmp = new Dog(name, year, bill, species, legs, spotty);
                al.add(tmp);
                break;
            case "cat":
                legs = input.nextInt();
                String eyeColor = input.next();
                tmp = new Cat(name, year, bill, species, legs, eyeColor);
                al.add(tmp);
                break;
            case "snake":
                String bloodtype = input.next();
                tmp = new Snake(name, year, bill, species, bloodtype);
                al.add(tmp);
                break;
            case "kangaroo":
                legs = input.nextInt();
                boolean pouch = input.nextBoolean();
                tmp = new Kangaroo(name, year, bill, species, legs, pouch);
                al.add(tmp);
                break;
            case "skunk":
                legs = input.nextInt();
                int stripes = input.nextInt();
                tmp = new Skunk(name, year, bill, species, legs, stripes);
                al.add(tmp);
                break;
        }
    }
    input.close();
    return al;
}

static void swapAnimal(Animal[] aa, int i, int j) {
        Animal tmp = aa[i];
        aa[i] = aa[j];
        aa[j] = tmp;
}

public String toString() {
    String x = String.format("| %-8s | %-8s | %-9d | $%-8.2f |", this.species, this.name, this.birthyear, this.bill);
    return x;
}

static void printAnimal(ArrayList<Animal> aa) {
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("| %-8s | %-8s | %-8s | %-9s | \n", "Species", "Name", "Birthyear", "Balance");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    for (Animal a: aa) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");
    }
}
```

And here is the input file:

```
2

Hopper
2003
555
Kangaroo
2
false

Kitty
2009
44
Cat
4
Green

Spot
2005
333
Dog
4
true

Johnny
2008
111
Cat
4
Blue

Striper
2011
432
Skunk
4
3

Edward
1995
630
Horse
4
true

Casper
1998
88
snake
ColdBlood

Boots
2005
987
Horse
4
false
```

As you can see, there are many different types of animals.
For some reason, the input.next() in getFromFile() is scanning:

```
Hopper
2
```

Instead of just scanning:

```
Hopper
```

A full zip of the project, including the other animal classes and the input file, can be downloaded at: [Download Zip Here!](https://www.mediafire.com/?tedvvwvm8smdpy2)
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to cut down your code to the smallest repoduceable problem. People don't want to sift through all your code, especially having to download it. Use a debugger and track down exactly where your problem is happening

Comment: I haven't digged too much into the code, but already saw a mistake. Before switch statement you do ```species.toLowerCase();``` which doesn't do anything, instead of ```switch(species.toLowerCase()) {```

Comment: I also suggested some changes. One mistake is defining `Animal tmp` in the first case, but using it without declaration in the other cases. I declared `Animal tmp` before the switch statement and also removed `al.add(tmp)` from each case and instead put it a single time after the switch statement.

Comment: @redFIVE I am a beginner, I will try to cut it down, I just thought that was the easiest way to explain it.

Comment: the easiest way to explain it is to reproduce your problem with the bare minimum amount of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not have all of the cases in the switch for the whole program to work. Thank you, @IliiazAkhmedov your solution as well as @CalvinP's solution helped me find the issue.

I was missing the horse case and a default case.

Thanks everyone for the help!